# Error tratando de filtrar registros usando un procedimiento almacenado

Tags: c#, stored-procedure

Estoy tratando de filtrar registros usando un proceso almacenado y cuando empiezo a introducir el titulo del registro en el textbox me sale un error.

**Procedimiento Alamacenado**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE filtrar_articulo 
@filtro varchar(45)
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT titulo, palabras_claves, correo_elec, localizacion, tipo from Articulos
    WHERE Titulo like @filtro + '%'

END
GO
```

**Clase Consulta**

```
public void filter(DataGridView data, string buscarTitulo)
{
    try
    {
        string Conexion = @"string de conexion";
        SqlConnection dataConnection = new SqlConnection(Conexion);
        SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand("filtrar_articulos", dataConnection);
        sql.CommandType  = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sql.Parameters.Add("@filtro",SqlDbType.VarChar, 45).Value= buscarTitulo;

        sql.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql);
        da.Fill(dt);
        data.DataSource = dt;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Los datos no se pudieron cargar: "+ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

**Y este es el mensaje que aparece **
[image]

Comment: Le falta dataConnection.Open();

Comment: Tiene razon @Simon pero la pregunta es...por que ejecutas un `ExecuteNonQuery`.Con `dt.Fill` es suficiente y no necesitas abrir la conexion

Comment: esta ejecutando dos veces la misma query...

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que ejecutas un `ExecuteNonQuery` innecesario, y este necesita que la conexión esté abierta para ejecutarse. Simplemente elimina esa linea, el método `Fill` ya abre y cierra la conexion y recupera los datos en el `DataTable`. Por otro lado, es conveniente para los objetos que implementan [`IDisposable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) el utilizar la estructura `using` en ellos para que los recursos que usan sean correctamente liberados:

```
public void filter(DataGridView data, string buscarTitulo)
{
    try
    {
        string Conexion = @"string de conexion";
        using (SqlConnection dataConnection = new SqlConnection(Conexion))
        {
            SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand("filtrar_articulos", dataConnection);
            sql.CommandType  = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sql.Parameters.Add("@filtro",SqlDbType.VarChar, 45).Value= buscarTitulo;

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql);
            da.Fill(dt);
            data.DataSource = dt;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Los datos no se pudieron cargar: "+ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta mal como lo estas llevando a cabo, no es necesario ejecutar ExecuteNonQuery para devolver un conjunto de datos. ExecuteNonQuery se suele utilizar para llevar a cabo una accion, como un abm.

Es por eso que es requerido abrir la conexion para ejecutar dicho metodo. Deberias quitar ExecuteNonQuery.

```
public void filter(DataGridView data, string buscarTitulo)
{
    try
    {
        string Conexion = @"string de conexion";
        SqlConnection dataConnection = new SqlConnection(Conexion);
        SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand("filtrar_articulos", dataConnection);
        sql.CommandType  = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sql.Parameters.Add("@filtro",SqlDbType.VarChar, 45).Value= buscarTitulo;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql);
        da.Fill(dt);
        data.DataSource = dt;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Los datos no se pudieron cargar: "+ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: podrias aclarar que la conexion deberia estar en un with, y que hay que cerrarla tambien?